# HERE maps: difference between positive and negative link ids

Tags: here-api

What is the difference between positive and negative link ids. For example link ids 781299767 and -781299767 have the same address, but only -781299767 has a speed limit. This can be seen from http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.xml?linkIds=781299767,-781299767&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL%20&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of LinkIdType defines the presence of the minus sign

"Permanent ID which references a network link. When presented with a minus sign
as the first character, this ID indicates that the link should be traversed in the
opposite direction of its default coding (for example, walking SW on a link that is coded as one-way traveling NE)."